How to set image in asp.net from mysql database. image is stored as longblob type in database
In asp.net web application(not MVC), I just tried to store and fetch image from database, I hope the image stores perfect but when retrieving, I just see a empty box.
let me give the code below
aspx file
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <%--<img runat="server" id ="im" src="./"/>--%>
<asp:Image runat="server" id="imm" height="500px" Width="500px"/>

</asp:Content>


aspx.cs file
 public partial class Dashboard : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
     MySqlConnection connection;
     byte[] fileBytes;
     string connectionString;

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         string connectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;password=root;database=eshopping;";
         MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
         string query = "SELECT image FROM products WHERE id=3";

         MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

         try
         {
             connection.Open();
             // Execute the query to fetch the image data
             object imageData = command.ExecuteScalar();

             if (imageData != null)
             {
                 // Convert the binary image data to a base64-encoded string
                 string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])imageData);
                 // Set the src attribute of the im element with the base64-encoded string
                 imm.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64String;
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             // Handle any exceptions
             // For example, you can log the error or display a message to the user
             System.Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
         }
         finally
         {
             // Close the database connection
             connection.Close();
         }

     }

 }

below is how i stored the image, do i made any mistake here?

    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = Name.Text;
    string price = TextBox1.Text;
    string quantitqnty = TextBox2.Text;
    string description = dis.Value.ToString();
    if (fileUploadImage.HasFile && price!="" && quantitqnty!="" && description !="")
    {
         fileBytes = fileUploadImage.FileBytes;
        string query = "insert into products (name,price,quantity,discription,image) values ('"+name+"','"+price+"','"+quantitqnty+"','"+description+"','"+fileBytes+"')";
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Image Selected to upload');", true);
        Name.Text = "";
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        TextBox2.Text = "";
        dis.Value = "";
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
    else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Select a image');", true);


    }
}

also when I see the data in sql workbench it just show it as BLOB
Workbench image is here
Here is value i got when I convert to base64string 

Hum, that code looks correct. Are you sure  the data is raw binary, or perhaps the data is already a base64 string? I would open up MySQL workbench and query that one row - take a look at the saved image data column -- maybe it already is a base 64 string?

You need debug it by yourself firstly make sure the imageData  contains the value and then check the base64String  is right .

@AlbertD.Kallal I have edited the post , now I gave the insert code and the image of workbench, kindly check it.

@BrandoZhang I check with make break point, that before ,I have zero byte in the variable, but after load image from database, I see some bytes in the variable.

But that screen shot does not show what's inside of that blob column. At least do a query that converts the blob to a string, or at least take a look at what exists inside of that column.  Even in above code, check the length of the byte array while debugging. How large is the blob column? how was the picture added to that blob? As noted, all these checks takes what, 1-2 minutes of your time. So far, with the posted code, what you have should work, so then this means what was saved in the blob column is empty, or is not a valid picture. When you query that one column, what is the length shown

@AlbertD.Kallal I added the image , The image has some value.

See my post below,  you can't insert binary data using a string.

I you cannot use string concatenation for a byte array for your insert command.
As a result, you should use parameter safe SQL to prevent SQL injections, but MORE so to ensure that the byte array is being saved.
Placing a byte array directly into a string for the insert command?
In most cases a string will not work, since such binary data will often have characters that represent the "end of string" such as ctrl-z, or even a char(0) for a null terminated string. Thus, you cannot use simple strings to insert binary data into the database, and you not have a valid byte array being saved into the database.
As a result, use parameters for that insert.
This is air code, but should be close:
    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fileUploadImage.HasFile && price != "" && quantitqnty != "" && description != "")
        {

            byte[] fileBytes = fileUploadImage.FileBytes;

            string query =
                "insert into products (name,price,quantity,discription,image) 
                values (@name, @price,@qty,@descript, @fileBytes)";

            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MyDB))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (MySqlCommand cmdSQL = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
                {

                    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.String).Value = Name.Text;
                    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@price", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = TextBox1.Text;
                    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@qty", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = TextBox2.Text;
                    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@descript", MySqlDbType.String).Value = dis.Value.ToString();
                    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@fileBytes", MySqlDbType.Blob).Value = fileBytes;

                    cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            // ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Image Selected to upload');", true);
            //Name.Text = "";
            //TextBox1.Text = "";
            //TextBox2.Text = "";
            //dis.Value = "";
            // above code makes ZERO sennse if you going to have a redirect
            // (and above code will never run with a re-direct anyway)
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        }
    }

